Compiling .vmap_c to .vmap (cs2 map)
I want to decompile .vmap_C file to .vmap in order to use it in Tree.js as vmap_c can't be used in Tree.js and also i don't have any alternative formats like .bsp
I tried to use GCFScape but it doesn't accept this format, also dota 2 workshop tools i get error reading file and cs 2 tools doesn't seem like have editor for maps
